# Use AWS Java SDK inside EMR Job

Tags: hadoop, serialization, jar, emr, scalding

I have a Scalding job packed in fatjar and running on EMR Hadoop cluster. Recently I added new feature requiring DynamoDB connection inside map. But as soon as mapper reaches DynamoDB initialization it throws following exception:

```
Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:172)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:166)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: cascading.flow.FlowException: internal error during mapper configuration
    at cascading.flow.hadoop.FlowMapper.configure(FlowMapper.java:102)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy7
Serialization trace:
connManager (com.amazonaws.http.impl.client.SdkHttpClient)
httpClient (com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient)
client (awscala.dynamodbv2.DynamoDBClient)
client (me.chuwy.enrich.hadoop.DuplicateStorage$DynamoDbStorage)
duplicateStorage (me.chuwy.enrich.hadoop.ShredJob)
$outer (me.chuwy.enrich.hadoop.ShredJob$$anonfun$11)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:138)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:115)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:610)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.read(FieldSerializer.java:599)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:221)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:648)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.read(FieldSerializer.java:605)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:221)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:648)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.read(FieldSerializer.java:605)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:221)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:648)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.read(FieldSerializer.java:605)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:221)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:729)
    at com.twitter.chill.SomeSerializer.read(SomeSerializer.scala:25)
    at com.twitter.chill.SomeSerializer.read(SomeSerializer.scala:19)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:648)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.read(FieldSerializer.java:605)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:221)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:648)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.read(FieldSerializer.java:605)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:221)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:729)
    at com.twitter.chill.SomeSerializer.read(SomeSerializer.scala:25)
    at com.twitter.chill.SomeSerializer.read(SomeSerializer.scala:19)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:729)
    at com.twitter.chill.SerDeState.readClassAndObject(SerDeState.java:61)
    at com.twitter.chill.KryoPool.fromBytes(KryoPool.java:94)
    at com.twitter.chill.Externalizer.fromBytes(Externalizer.scala:145)
    at com.twitter.chill.Externalizer.maybeReadJavaKryo(Externalizer.scala:158)
    at com.twitter.chill.Externalizer.readExternal(Externalizer.scala:148)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1839)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1997)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1921)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1997)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1921)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1997)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1921)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1897)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1997)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1921)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1997)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1921)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at cascading.flow.hadoop.util.JavaObjectSerializer.deserialize(JavaObjectSerializer.java:101)
    at cascading.flow.hadoop.util.HadoopUtil.deserializeBase64(HadoopUtil.java:312)
    at cascading.flow.hadoop.util.HadoopUtil.deserializeBase64(HadoopUtil.java:293)
    at cascading.flow.hadoop.FlowMapper.configure(FlowMapper.java:81)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy7
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass
```

I *think* that problem may be in that EMR AMI is shipping with its own jars in `/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/` and they conflict with libs that I include in fat jar, I tried to delete them, but then other EMR steps are failing.

Comment: What AWS Java SDK dependencies (and versions) are you including in your fat jar? Since, as you mentioned, EMR currently includes AWS Java SDK 1.10.x in /usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk, including a different version of the AWS Java SDK in your fat jar could definitely cause issues at runtime. You might be able to shade/relocate the version you are including in your jar (see the maven-shade-plugin if you are using Maven), but sometimes that causes other issues.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanKelly. I use 1.10.77 as transitive dependency, but I tried different versions from ~1.10.56 to ~1.11.30. I also tried to exclude them from fat jar and override EMR jars with same versions as in fat jar. Result is still the same. Now I suspect that problem is in OpenJDK which is way to run jars on EMR.

Comment: Ah, OK, EMR has used AWS Java SDK 1.10.75.1 for a while and has not yet upgraded to 1.11.x, so bundling 1.11.x with your app would likely cause issues. If you use 1.10.75.1 as a "provided" dependency (which will cause your app to be compiled against this version but not include it in the fat jar), does that help anything?

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't. I tried to exclude from fatjar (which should have same effect as "provided" for transitive dependency) aws-core, aws-dynamodb, httpcore, httpclient. But still same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in Scalding serialization, not in binary incompatibility as I suspected initially. DynamodDB client is not serializable entity, because it contains things like handlers, thread pools, etc. Therefore it should be initialized straight inside job **and** declared as [lazy val](https://github.com/twitter/scalding/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#q-im-getting-a-notserializableexception-on-hadoop-job-submission).